# WeatherAPI как получить погоду несколько дней назад

Tags: python, api, openweathermap

В качестве api использую openweathermap.org. У меня стоит задача, чтобы пользователь мог указать дату, на какое число он хочет получить погоду, и она ему вывелась. Только как получить не текущую погоду, а в прошлом, или в будущем?

Comment: Вы используете HTTP api. А ваш пользователь что использует?

Comment: пользователь использует веб-интерфейс. Но это не особо важно в этой задаче

Comment: То есть вопрос можно свести к тому как по апи openweathermap.org можно получить погоду на указанный день?

Comment: Вот в документации описано как это сделать https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-3#history. Позволяет указать timestamp и получить исторические данные и прогноз на 4 дня вперед максимум.
А вот с агрегацией по дню https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-3#history_daily_aggregation. С агрегацией по дню позволяет получить прогноз аж на 1,5 года вперед.

Comment: Все, спасибо, благодарю